# Lines are not highlighted

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to find the outline of the lines. To further find words and symbols. But for some reason my code doesn't work and I can't figure out what it is.
I'm trying to find lines in this image [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgixf.jpg)

Here's my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
#import image
image = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\dennn\\PycharmProjects\\untitled2\\output.jpg')
#cv2.imshow('orig',image)
#cv2.waitKey(0)
#grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
#binary
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow('second',thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
#dilation0000
kernel = np.ones((5,100), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
cv2.imshow('dilated',img_dilation)
cv2.waitKey(0)
#find contours
ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(img_dilation.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#sort contours
sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
    # Get bounding box
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
    # Getting ROI
    roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    # show ROI
    cv2.imshow('segment no:'+str(i),roi)
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),( x + w, y + h ),(90,0,255),2)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imshow('marked areas',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

My output image. [The output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPVUU.jpg)
I want to receive [I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwWnI.jpg)
I don't have sort contours working.
During the debugger, I get the following image, it is only this (the program freezes) [show ROI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e04Mg.jpg)

[Here is the solution to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59686943/increase-space-between-text-lines-in-image/59689169#59689169)

Comment: What does “doesn’t work” mean - please edit into your question details of what your code does and why that isn’t what you want it to do. If you get a Python error message, edit the __full__ text of the error message (I.e. include the stack/traceback) into your question. If the output images aren’t what you want, include the output image for the input image you provide.

Comment: @barny I added what I get and what I want.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: @barny fixed code.

Comment: `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` tells `cv2.findContours` to find only the extreme outer contour. See https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html

Comment: I tried everything-Contour Retrieval Mode, I couldn't find all the lines

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59686943/increase-space-between-text-lines-in-image/59689169#59689169) may be helpful.