# How to use vertical dilation in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I cordially need help with a procedure.

I'm trying to make the image sharper but my biggest challenge is that many times the letters end up being too close together (as is the case with number 4 in the image), I tried a dilatation but it damages the image a lot periodically depending on its intensity .

Is there a possibility (in python) that I managed to leave it in the way of the final example?

[image: Original Image. My version has the gray backgroung taken care of.]

[image: This is a version of the image that I come up with using the opening version:]

[image: This is a version of the image that I come up with using the opening version:]

Change the initial gray for black_white.

```
mrz = cv2.resize(initial_img, (800, 140))
    black_white = cv2.threshold(mrz, 0, 255, 
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

My code:

```
img = cv2.resize(img, (400, 70))
    black_white = cv2.threshold(mrz, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)     
    cv2.imshow("Black-White", black_white)

    dist = cv2.distanceTransform(black_white, cv2.DIST_L2, 5)
    dist = cv2.normalize(dist, dist, 0, 1.0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    dist = (dist * 255).astype("uint8")
    cv2.imshow("Dist", dist)

    black_white = cv2.threshold(dist, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    cv2.imshow("black_white", black_white)

    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(black_white, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    img_erosion = cv2.erode(opening, kernel, iterations=1)

    final = cv2.bitwise_and(opening.copy(), opening)
```

Comment: instead of making the structuring element and ellipse of size (3,3) you can make it more elongated in the vertical axis

Comment: There is a great answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59686943/increase-space-between-text-lines-in-image

Comment: (Sembei Noramaki)

This doesn't work very well...
The more I stretch the axis, the more damaged the image tends to get...

Comment: SecurityObscurity

Seems like a good article, but it's messing with horizontal lines, I'll try to look better to try this as a base for a vertical solution.

Comment: Can you post the original, unprocessed image?

Comment: @SecurityObscurity The problem with this article is that the image in it has characters that are already separated by some space. If you look at my images, the numbers have spots connecting them, making it almost impossible to distinguish the individual bounding box of each number.

Comment: @stateMachine Original picture posted